# JGit DiffEntry shows not existent commited files

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm trying to iterate through all existent commits to store information (author, committer, timestamp, file, ...) about it. Its working pretty fine, but sometime the current commit shows non existent entries. I compared it against the original commit on GitHub and the graphical user interface of the local git repo as well. Is something wrong with my code or do think in the wrong way about it?

```
private void getInformation() {
    Repository repository = new FileRepository(path);
    Git git = new Git(repository);
    RevCommit oldCommit = null;
    DiffFormatter diffFormatter = null;
    RevWalk walk = null;
    boolean first = true;

    walk = new RevWalk(repository);
    walk.markStart(walk.parseCommit(repository.resolve("HEAD")));
    walk.sort(RevSort.REVERSE);

    for (RevCommit commit : walk) {

        if (first == true) {
            oldCommit = commit;
            first = false;
        }

        /* read the old and new commit ID to determine changes (method by Rüdiger Herrmann) */
        ObjectReader reader = git.getRepository().newObjectReader();
        CanonicalTreeParser oldTree = parseRawGitdata(git, commit, reader);
        CanonicalTreeParser newTree = parseRawGitdata(git, oldCommit, reader);
        diffFormatter = new DiffFormatter(DisabledOutputStream.INSTANCE);
        diffFormatter.setRepository(git.getRepository());
        diffFormatter.setDetectRenames(true);
        List<DiffEntry> entries = diffFormatter.scan(newTree, oldTree);

        if (!entries.isEmpty()) {
            for (DiffEntry entry : entries) {
                /* only .java class files are relevant */
                if (entry.getOldPath().endsWith(".java") || entry.getNewPath().endsWith(".java")) {
                    /* handle the current ChangeType... */
                    determineChangeType(entry, commit);
                }
            }
        }
        oldCommit = commit;
    }

    diffFormatter.close();
    walk.close();    
}

private CanonicalTreeParser parseRawGitdata(Git git, RevCommit commit, ObjectReader reader) {

    CanonicalTreeParser treeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
    ObjectId tree = git.getRepository().resolve(commit.getTree().getName());
    treeIter.reset(reader, tree);

    return treeIter;
}
```

I just want to start (or end after changing the order) at the current HEAD. For example looking at the DiffEntry of the commit "**af50018f11d4fdfa8ac04a55f942a4973cb15c87**" from the open source project Apache Struts, it contains around 1170 items:

```
DiffEntry[MODIFY .gitignore],   
DiffEntry[MODIFY apps/pom.xml],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/README.txt],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/pom.xml],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/exo/web.xml],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/gridsphere/README-gridsphere.txt],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/gridsphere/gridsphere-portlet.xml],     
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/gridsphere/group.xml],  
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/gridsphere/layout.xml],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/gridsphere/struts-portlet],    
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/gridsphere/web.xml],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/jbossportal2.0/jboss-app.xml],  
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/jbossportal2.0/jboss-portlet.xml],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/jbossportal2.0/jboss-web.xml],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/jbossportal2.0/portlet-instances.xml],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/jbossportal2.0/struts-portlet-pages.xml],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/jbossportal2.2/jboss-app.xml],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/jbossportal2.2/jboss-portlet.xml],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/jbossportal2.2/jboss-web.xml],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/jbossportal2.2/struts-portlet-object.xml],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/jetspeed2/README-jetspeed2.txt],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/jetspeed2/struts-portlet.psml],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/etc/liferay3.6.1/web.xml],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/portlet/example/ExampleAction.java],   
DiffEntry[DELETE apps/portlet/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/portlet/example/FormExample.java],   
...
```

According to GitHub, the auhor committed on 1 Aug 2016 (af50018f11d4fdfa8ac04a55f942a4973cb15c87) - 76 additions and 17 deletions.

```
+27 −16 core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/views/util/DefaultUrlHelper.java
+49 −1 core/src/test/java/org/apache/struts2/views/util/DefaultUrlHelperTest.java
```

Why is my DiffEntry set containing so much data that is not part of the official commit?

Is JGit providing also uncommitted data that floods the previous data structure?